# How to access struct with CURLINFO_PRIVATE in libcurl?

Tags: c, pointers, curl, struct, libcurl

I have been scratching my head about this for hours, I'm trying to access my struct from CURLINFO_PRIVATE, but gcc doesn't seem to recognize it as a struct:

```
10-at-a-time.c: In function 'main':
10-at-a-time.c:148:48: error: request for member 'size' in something not a structure or union
 printf("%lu bytes retrieved\n", (long)chunk->size);
                                            ^
10-at-a-time.c:152:15: error: request for member 'memory' in something not a structure or union
 free(chunk->memory);
```

In the libcurl documentation it says it will return a char pointer: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_PRIVATE.html

As far as I have understood, I should be able to dereference that pointer with the "->" syntax and get the struct instance. But that doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code, I hope it's easy to understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>    

#include <curl/multi.h>    

struct MemoryStruct {
    char *memory;
    size_t size;
};

static size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    struct MemoryStruct *mem = (struct MemoryStruct *)userp;

    mem->memory = realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
    if(mem->memory == NULL) {
        /* out of memory! */ 
        printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
        return 0;
    }

    memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
    mem->size += realsize;
    mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;

    return realsize;
}    

static const char *urls[] = {
    "http://www.microsoft.com",
    "http://www.opensource.org",
    "http://www.google.com",
    "http://www.bbc.co.uk",
    "http://www.newslink.org",
    "http://www.un.org",
    "http://www.news.com",
    "http://www.cnn.com",
    "http://www.wikipedia.org",
    "http://www.dell.com",
    "http://www.hp.com",
    "http://www.cert.org",
    "http://www.mit.edu",
    "http://www.nist.gov",
    "http://www.ebay.com",
    "http://www.playstation.com",
    "http://www.uefa.com",
    "http://www.ieee.org",
    "http://www.apple.com",
    "http://www.symantec.com"
};

#define count sizeof(urls)/sizeof(char*)  

static void init(CURLM *cm, int i)
{
    CURL *eh = curl_easy_init();    

    struct MemoryStruct chunk;

    chunk.memory = malloc(1);  /* will be grown as needed by the realloc above */ 
    chunk.size = 0;    /* no data at this point */     

    curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);
    curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_URL, urls[i]);
    curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_PRIVATE, (void *)&chunk);
    curl_easy_setopt(eh, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0L);
    curl_multi_add_handle(cm, eh);
}

int main(void)
{
    int bots = 10;    

    if (count < bots) {
        bots = count;
    }    

    CURLM *cm;
    CURLMsg *msg;
    long L;
    struct timeval timeout;
    unsigned int current = 0;    

    int msg_queue = -1;
    int handles = -1;
    int maxfd = -1;    

    fd_set fdread;
    fd_set fdwrite;
    fd_set fdexcep;    

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    cm = curl_multi_init();    

    curl_multi_setopt(cm, CURLMOPT_MAXCONNECTS, (long)bots);

    for (current = 0; current < bots; ++current) {
        init(cm, current);
    }

    while (handles) {
        curl_multi_perform(cm, &handles);

        if (handles) {
            FD_ZERO(&fdread);
            FD_ZERO(&fdwrite);
            FD_ZERO(&fdexcep);

            if (curl_multi_fdset(cm, &fdread, &fdwrite, &fdexcep, &maxfd)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "E: curl_multi_fdset\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            if (curl_multi_timeout(cm, &L)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "E: curl_multi_timeout\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }    

            if (L == -1) {
                L = 100;
            }

            if (maxfd == -1) {
                sleep((unsigned int)L / 1000);
            }
            else {
                timeout.tv_sec = L / 1000;
                timeout.tv_usec = (L % 1000) * 1000;

                if (0 > select(maxfd + 1, &fdread, &fdwrite, &fdexcep, &timeout)) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "E: select(%i,,,,%li): %i: %s\n", maxfd + 1, L, errno, strerror(errno));
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
            }
        }

        while ((msg = curl_multi_info_read(cm, &msg_queue))) {
            if (msg->msg == CURLMSG_DONE) {
                char *chunk;
                CURL *e = msg->easy_handle;
                curl_easy_getinfo(msg->easy_handle, CURLINFO_PRIVATE, &chunk);
                fprintf(stderr, "R: %d - %s\n", msg->data.result, curl_easy_strerror(msg->data.result));    

                printf("%lu bytes retrieved\n", (long)chunk->size);

                curl_multi_remove_handle(cm, e);
                curl_easy_cleanup(e);
                free(chunk->memory);
            }
            else {
                fprintf(stderr, "E: CURLMsg (%d)\n", msg->msg);
            }    

            if (current < count) {
                init(cm, current++);
                handles++;
            }
        }
    }

    curl_multi_cleanup(cm);
    curl_global_cleanup();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am new to C btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the private pointer:

```
ptr = [something];
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PRIVATE, ptr);
```

Extract the pointer again from the handle it was set in:

```
curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_PRIVATE, &ptr);
```

In your case, when you extract the pointer again you need to make sure you have it as the correct struct pointer and not just a `char *`. Like perhaps:

```
struct MemoryStruct *chunk;
curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_PRIVATE, &chunk);
```

... as then you can access the struct and its fields.

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel, that works perfectly. I didn't think it would be so easy :)